# How do I pad a number with 0's to the left while using the range function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the variable 'time' to be a range of numbers and pad all of them with 0's so that they are all 4 numbers long.

Right now, I am working with the range (1,7). I want an output of 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, 0005, and 0006. I put time(or t, it doesn't really matter)=range(0001,0007) but that doesn't work. Then I tried time=range(1,7).zfill(4) but that also didn't work. Then I did:
a=range(1,7)
for t=a.zfill(4)
but i got an invalid syntax error.

Comment: What you're doing with this variable later? Integers in Python cannot have leading zeros, so best you can do is convert it to a string with those leading zeros, but then you cannot treat it as a number anymore.

Comment: @Barmar zfill is a method on `str`, not on `int`.  Don't answer in the comments, because they can't be downvoted... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string formatting to do the same.

```
for x in range(1, 7):
    print(f'{x:04}')
```

Output:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
```

Answer (score -1):

Another old school method is str(10000+x)[-4:]

Comment: Downvote, really?  What doesn't this do to answer the question about zero-fill?